# Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

I face the following error when adding the migration of database in .net core

This is the error:

[image]

This is the code in `Startup`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
           
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddControllers();
}
```

This is the `ApplicationDbContext` class:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `ApplicationUser`:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
    public string UserFName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserLName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images, post code (see [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)). On a side-note, please check the [C# Coding Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) using non-standard naming conventions makes the code much harder to read for any C# developer ;)

Comment: @Tseng I Do That :)

Comment: On top of the comments below my answer, your question is rather misldeading. What version are you using? Question is tagged asp.net core 2.0 and 2.1, but your error message mentions 3.1 ??? So: a) which Version of ASP.NET Core are you using? b) which verison of the SDKs you have installed?

Comment: i change tag of my question to version 3.0 and 3.1 of .net core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you are your inheritance is wrong.

```
public ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
```

should be

```
public ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

or

```
public ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>
```

if you also extend roles class.

when you want to create an context with an extended user class (instead of `IdentityUser`)

Comment: i use public `ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` but the same error :(

Comment: Show your Program.cs file, not sure if you are using some outdated pattern (i.e. dotnet tooling method names from 2.1 but having a 3.0 or 3.1 application

Comment: Dont post code/extended information in comments, update your question...

Comment: `CreateHostBuilder` is for ASP.NET Core 2.1 and newer. If you are still targeting ASP.NET Core 2.0, it won't be recognized and should be called `BuildWebhost`. See [migration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-3.1#changes-to-take-advantage-of-the-new-code-based-idioms-that-are-recommended-in-aspnet-core-21). The naming and return type of that method is important for the `dotnet` tooling to work (such as ef core command lines and migrations), since it look look in this method to know how to instantiate a DbContext for the migrations

Answer (score 92):

I found the cause of this error could be multiple things in your code. For me at least, the best way was to add verbose in command.

With that will be able to understand what is the problem. the `verbose` will display all steps of the execution.

In visual studio use:

```
add-migration Added_something -verbose
```

For the CLI use:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Added_something  --verbose
```

Comment: apparently this should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, thanks to `verbose`, I was able to identify that I forgot to add a parameterless constructor in my `DbContext` implementation and other issues.

Comment: Yes, this is the much better answer. My solution was totally different than others, but -verbose found it easily.  "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish, you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: ```---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' while attempting to activate [YourContext].```

Answer (score 36):

This error can also occur if multiple startup projects is selected. I set my webproject to startup project and that solved the issue for me.

Comment: This was also the case for me. I think it couldn't load the settings from the appsettings.json, because that was handled by the startup.cs.

Comment: you saved my bacon (or the vegan equivalent). Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks. If `AppDbContext`, the migrations and the model classes are defined in a Class Library separate from the project where `appsettings.json` and `Startup.cs` are located, you need to mark that project as the Startup Project (by right clicking on it) before executing `Update-Database`.

Comment: Thank you @Pelle the solution is spot on.

Comment: Wow! Who would've thought about this :)

Answer (score 27):

My problem was solved by installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` nuget package.

this package is required for the **Entity Framework Core Tools** to work. Ensure your **startup project** is correct.then install the package.

at the end **Build -> Clean Solution** in your project and then try running your command again.

[Help Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60979023/5576498)

**add** migration command cli:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitDatabase --project YourDataAccessLibraryName -s YourWebProjectName -c YourDbContextClassName --verbose
```

**update** database command cli:

```
dotnet ef database update InitDatabase --project YourDataAccessLibraryName -s YourWebProjectName -c YourDbContextClassName --verbose
```

**remove** migration command cli:

```
dotnet ef migrations remove --project YourDataAccessLibraryName -s YourWebProjectName -c YourDbContextClassName --verbose
```

[Entity Framework Core tools reference - .NET Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)

Answer (score 19):

I also had same problem today when I was running the `dotnet ef migrations add <MigrationName>`

I had three project, MainApp (Web), C# Project with DBContext and C# Project for Models.

I was able to resolve it from CLI.

```
dotnet ef migrations add AddCategoryTableToDb -s MainApp -p ProjectHavingDbContext
```

Comment: consider the path too the startup(main) project.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me! I ran this command from solution root directory.

Comment: This was what worked for me, in VS 2022 running the command from Developer Powershell from solution root directory. NuGet Package Manager console was working fine.

Comment: Adding the startup project to the CLI worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I had the same error when I had two constructors of my DbContext. After rearranging constructors order to parameterless constructor being first in the class fixed it. e.g.

```
public ProgramDbContext() : base()
{
}
public ProgramDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProgramDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
}
```

It must be something with dynamic DbContext object invocation with Reflection playing here.

Comment: Thanks! This one helped me while upgrading to .netcore 3.1 from 2.2

Comment: apparently, you need to have two constructors. I was missing the first one.

Comment: Yep, this helped me - you need to have a parameterless constructor :)

Comment: YES! The First Constructor must be the Parameter-less one. Thank you so much. That's an awkward error thought.

Comment: note: add : base() for first constructor is MUST

Answer (score 6):

This error also can occur if you remove the `static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)` method from Program.cs for your .net core app. (This was my case)

Comment: Same here. I have added additional parameter to this method, that's why it broke.

Answer (score 5):

## *Try This one as of March 2021 - VS 16.9.2*

I tried many of the above answers and none worked for me. My issue was that we had multiple startup projects, so that was step one. Just set a single startup project, so I set our `Data` project to be the startup. Still got the error. Then it hit me (thanks to the @AFetter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61982219/373438)) the `Data` project does NOT have a connection string within it. So I set my startup project to one with an `appSettings.json` file that HAS a connection to the DB and then made sure the Package Manager Console's Default Project was set to the `Data` project and reran the command to create the migration and it worked!

Comment: This one worked. Good job!

Comment: Perfect!!! Good Job!

Answer (score 4):

If you come to this issue while using .Net 6 along with the new [minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0), check that you're not calling `builder.build()` before calling the `AddDbContext` on `builder.services`.

```
using MyProject.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
string relativePath = ".";
string databasePath = Path.Combine(relativePath, "MyDb.sqlite");


builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={databasePath}") //connection string
        );

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}



app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Excellent! such an easy miss!  looked all over but I guess during the transition from startup.cs to the new minimal hosting (program.cs) people like myself are missing little things like this!  thank you!  fixed the issue in the new dotnet 6 way!

Answer (score 2):

I found I was missing:

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tool`
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`

I had multiple startup projects (different API's).
I was at a different level in the PM console.
Then I learned I had to close SQL management so I can run PM console commands.

Comment: Please just explain a clear step by step of how someone else would replicate your solution without apology. Sometimes a new answer can be useful to someone later on. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

**I faced the same problem in .Net 6**
[Make sure that AddDBContext is above builder.Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNoIs.png)

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseDBContext>(options => 
  options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection"))
);
var app = builder.Build();
```

In the `Program.cs` file, do not write anything with builder.Services.... below

```cs
var app = builder.Build()
```

line otherwise it throughs an error.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while running the dot net ef migrations script command from the azure pipeline task. I did added "-project" argument. But still was failing.
Adding the "-startup-project" argument worked for me.
I guess even though we specify startup class in project , for ef tool to find one we have to explicitly mention them.

Answer (score 1):

**In my case, I was missing a property in appsettings.json that was showing as Warning instead of Error**

This error message is sometimes not directly related to the db context model. Check other errors in your Startup class such as missing properties/ credentials in your appsettings.json/ appsettings.Development.json

run your migration with the --verbose option to see all errors and warnings

```
dotnet ef migrations add YourMigrationName  --verbose
```

Answer (score 1):

Read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory

The tooling tries to create a design-time DB context instance using various methods. One of those methods is to look for an implementation of the `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`.

> Some of the EF Core Tools commands (for example, the Migrations
> commands) require a derived DbContext instance to be created at design
> time in order to gather details about the application's entity types
> and how they map to a database schema. In most cases, it is desirable
> that the DbContext thereby created is configured in a similar way to
> how it would be configured at run time.

Here's how your DB context factory class might look like:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> {
    public BlazorContext CreateDbContext(string[] args) {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=db.sqlite3");

        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Docker-Compose project. You need to unload the Docker-Compose project and then clean and rebuild the solution and set the startup project.

It worked for me to create the migration in EFCore.

Answer (score 0):

Although OP faced the issue seemingly due incorrect usage of base classes provided by AspNet Identity, but usually we come across this error when an instance of ApplicationDbContext could not be created at design time. There are couple of solutions for this. One of them is to specify the ApplicationDbContext provider in ConfigureServices method in StartUp class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection"));
    });
}
```

For other solutions, please have a look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#onconfiguring

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error....except the code was working fine just minutes before.
I was in the process of replacing some property attributes with `Fluent API`

I had three projects: WebApp, DataAccess Library and Model Library.

After trying a few unsuccessful stabs at messing with migrations...I ended up doing a `Build->Clean Solution` and doing a build on the WebApp.
Every thing was working again...and I could not recreate the error.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me, but at the same time I also had a `An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Could not parse the JSON file.`

Fixing my `appsettings.json` file resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, just modify the program class. Net Core 3.0

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

To

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>() 
            .Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was due to me storing my data types and migrations in a separate "Data" project and accidentally having it set as a startup project rather than my actual startup project.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same error...

> Here's how I got there:
>  Created a new ASP.NET Core Web App
> (Model-View-Controller)
>  Target Framework was .NET Core 3.1
> (LTS)
>  Authentication Type: Individual Accounts

Once the project was created...I wanted to be able to modify the register/login process.(but these pages are part of the Razor Class Library)
So to get the pages in the project: I right click the project `Add->New Scaffolded Item...`
And picked `Identity`... 
Next I needed to `Add-Migration InitIdentity`...and this is where the errors/trouble starts.

I tried reading and working through some of the other answers with no success.
I found a solution by:
Creating the project like (above)
**But this time I decided NOT to Scaffold Identity.(yet)**

I put a connection string in the `application.config` and ran the project.
I did this before Add-Migration.
I went in to register...A screen came up and said the migration hasnt run yet and had a button to run the migration. I press it and did a refresh and all was good. 
Its at this point I went back to the project and did a `Add->Scafolded Item...`and now there is no error and I have the Auth screens to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Thoroughly inspect your appsettings file and endure it is well formed. Lookout fro missing characters or unnecessary characters

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using  a custom `IdentityErrorDescriber` :

```
  services.AddIdentity<AppIdentityUser, AppIdentityRole>()
              .AddErrorDescriber<MyIdentityErrorDescriber>() // comment this !
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

and in my `MyIdentityErrorDescriber` I was using resources to translate errors.
and when I comment out the  `.AddErrorDescriber<MyIdentityErrorDescriber>()` line the migration worked without any errors. I think the problem is either with the `IdentityErrorDescriber` or Resources.

Answer (score 0):

I had three projects, one with Api, second with Models and third with ApplicationDbContext. Api project was starting project. I've added **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design** nuget package to Api project (it's the starting project) and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and when I added this it worked fine:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr")));
            services.AddScoped<IuserRepositorhy, UserRepository>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had two Configurations for Connection Strings in the app settings file, both missing a comma to separate both. When I put the comma, the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be your issue, but this is what caused the error on my end. If your app loads an environment variable at build time, that variable should be declared in the terminal. In my case, my app loaded my `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` from a json file. I needed to export that variable before running anything related to build.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, a simple gotcha, has got me before.

Make sure you **actually** have a value inside of the connection string in your appsettings.json file.

I.e.

This will throw an error:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": ""
  },
```

This will not:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=server;Database=db;User Id=user;Password=password!;"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error ocurred when i copied a project from tutorial repository. I managed to solve it by updating the project packages through NuGet Package Manager.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32894193)

Answer (score 0):

I found that doing the following fixed this for me within my ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database={DbName};Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

This does appear to be something which changes from user to user.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to create the migration from my class library project.

Nuget packages installed:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
  All my models and the context are located in that project.
  There is one little detail. 
   When you run the migrations the builder is looking for the constructor. 
  After digging through the documentation I found this: [constructor without parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#using-a-constructor-with-no-parameters) 
  This is how my **DatabaseContext** looks like:

```
public class RandomDataContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<YourCustomModel> YourCustomModels { get; set; }

    public RandomDataContext()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("your_connection_string");
    }

}
```

After running this in the package manager console:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration --project YourProjectName
```

Then

```
dotnet ef database update --project YourProjectName
```

I had this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830824/instance-failure-in-asp-net) 
And when I solved it, my database was created.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**In My Case** in MS Visual Studio2022 .Net 6 *reinstall NuGET Packages*

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Version 6.0.12
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design Version 6.0.12
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version 6.0.12
4. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools Version 6.0.12

Alter My DbContext ..

```bash
using Leagues.Models.Domains;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Leagues.Models.Context {
    public partial class FifaDbContext:DbContext {
        public FifaDbContext()
        {

        }
        public FifaDbContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
        {
        
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder); 
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 
        }
        public virtual DbSet<League> Leagues { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Club> Clubs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Point> Points { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Confirm My AppSettings

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "FiFa": "Data Source=DESKTOP-R34I8VP;Initial Catalog=FiFaWorldCup;Integrated Security=True;"
  }
}
```

Confirm Program.cs

```
using Leagues.Models.Context;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var ConnectionStrings = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("FiFa");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<FifaDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(ConnectionStrings));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();



var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Add-Migration

[image]

Update-Database

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem,
this error can appear for many reasons but for my case was because of removing something in **program.cs class (startup.cs in older than dotnet 6)**
and I removed

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

accidently and when added this to my class the error fixed
I hope this help you

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33507542)

Answer (score 0):

After spending 2 hours, it turned out that there was one wrong character in the middle of my db password in connection string :(

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run an incorrect dependency injection.

Instead of this...

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

modify to this...

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

or this...

```
var connection = builder.Configuration.getConnectionstring("DefaultConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced this error when I forgot to do this in Startup.cs.

```
services.AddTransient<IExcelMasterRepository, ExcelMasterRepository>();
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I had to delete old snapshot and migration.
Steps I took were:

1. Right-click on Migrations folder
2. Open folder in File Explorer
3. Select & Delete all