# How to add first/last name properties to Identity user in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am building a website using ASP.NET Core MVC. I scaffolded the identity pages and am attempting to add the first and last name properties to the registration form. I am stuck on where to set the user's first/last name based on the input from the form. Below is the `Register.cshtml.cs` file that I scaffolded.

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
#nullable disable

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueTracker.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IUserStore<IdentityUser> _userStore;
        private readonly IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser> _emailStore;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            IUserStore<IdentityUser> userStore,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public class InputModel
        {
            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "First Name")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }


        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = CreateUser();

                await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }

        private IdentityUser CreateUser()
        {
            try
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance<IdentityUser>();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(IdentityUser)}'. " +
                    $"Ensure that '{nameof(IdentityUser)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor, or alternatively " +
                    $"override the register page in /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml");
            }
        }

        private IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser> GetEmailStore()
        {
            if (!_userManager.SupportsUserEmail)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("The default UI requires a user store with email support.");
            }
            return (IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser>)_userStore;
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing has been changed from the scaffolded file, except I added in the following properties.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Last Name")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

In other posts on here, I have seen that I need to add these properties to the OnPostAsync method; however, every tutorial has a different method than mine.

For example, other tutorials show that in the OnPostAsync method, I should have the following code to assign the first/last name properties:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email, FirstName = Input.FirstName, LastName = Input.LastName };
```

However, my file is missing this instantiation and only calls the CreateUser method.

I am not sure where I can properly assign the properties to a new user. I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC and identity so sorry if this is a simple issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the default `IdentityUser` does not have `FirstName` and `LastName` properties, So you need custom identity.

First, Create a model to inherit from identiyUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, Change

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityScaffoldedContext>();
```

to

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityScaffoldedContext>();
```

in Program.cs.

Change your dbcontext:

```
public class xxxContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public IdentityScaffoldedContext(DbContextOptions<xxxContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Finally, Migration and update database, Now your identity User will have `FirstName` and 'LastName' properties:

[image]

More details you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Thank you so much! What do you mean about finally migration and update database?

Comment: When you follow the steps i provied, The Identity User will have firstname and lastname properties, But the identity user table hasn't beed updated, You need to migration and update the database to make identity user table add firstname and lastname colums

Comment: So I created the ApplicationUser model within the Models folder, changed program.cs as you said, and changed the DbContext file. To migration and update the database, I have followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0 . However, I am encountering an error whenever I try to update the database. It says: "Unable to create an object of type 'IssueTrackerIdentityDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728".

Comment: Have your set your project as startup project? You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796411/unable-to-create-an-object-of-type-applicationdbcontext-for-the-different-pat)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the first and last name or custom fields after the CreateUser() method like below:

```
var user = CreateUser();
user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
user.LastName = Input.LastName;

await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```

More details: [Add custom user data to the Identity DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)