# Unable to create an object of type 'DbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am developing a three-layer project on WPF core 6.0. I can not create migration models in the database. when calling the add-migration command, an error occurs: Unable to create an object of type 'FactoryDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

my data context:

```
public class FactoryDbContext : DbContext
{               
    public FactoryDbContext(DbContextOptions<FactoryDbContext> options) : base(options) { }        
    internal DbSet<Budget>? Budgets { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Employee>? Employees { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<FinishedProducts>? FinishedProducts { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Ingredients>? Ingredients { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Measurement>? Measurements { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Position>? Positions { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Production>? Productions { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<PurchaseRaw>? PurchaseRaws { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Raw>? Raws { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Sell>? Sells { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<Salary>? Salaries { get; set; }      

}
```

my App class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private IServiceProvider? serviceProvider;    
    
    private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

        serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var mainWindow = serviceProvider.GetService<MainWindow>();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<FactoryDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(new DataBaseConfiguration().sqlConnectionString));
        services.AddScoped<IGlobalRepository, GlobalRepository>();
        services.AddScoped(typeof(MainWindow));
    }
}
```

Tried inserting the data string directly - to no avail.

Comment: You could try the command with -verbose and see if you get more info. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796411/unable-to-create-an-object-of-type-applicationdbcontext-for-the-different-pat

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but may be this issue due to your
all DbSet is nullable try with non-nullable DbSet
and also use public instead of internal
like

```
internal DbSet<Budget>? Budgets { get; set; }
```

replace with

```
public DbSet<Budget> Budgets { get; set; }
```

and then try to create migration.